# Jasmine Test Explorer is showing typescript jasmine tests in VS Code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, jasmine, explorer

[image]I am using Jasmine Test explorer for angular typescript. When we create a angular component, the *spec.ts also created, so the spec.ts files are scattered all over the project. 
is my spec_dir value correct? Also let me know , what i am missing ?

Below is Jasmine.json

```
    {
    "spec_dir": "${workspaceFolder}/angularProject/src/app",
    "spec_files": [
        "**/*[sS]pec.ts"
    ],
    "helpers": [
        "helpers/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
    "random": true
}
```

Below is settings.json

```
{
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "gitlens.views.repositories.branches.layout": "list",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "jasmineExplorer.cwd": "test",
    "jasmineExplorer.logfile": "jasminexplorer.log",
    "jasmineExplorer.logpanel": true,
    "jasmineExplorer.config": "${workspaceFolder}/angularProject/spec/support/jasmine.json"
}
```

Comment: did you found a way?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `jasmineExplorer.nodeArgv` configuration property with `["-r", "ts-node/register"]` value to your `settings.json` ([see TypeScript support section](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-jasmine-test-adapter)).